# proper construction of a list

Tags: lists, style-manuals

In a list, the last item is preceded by "and". This sentence appeared in a recent Foreign Affairs article:

*The United States **and** its allies and partners are imposing harsh costs on Moscow.*

Shouldn't the *and* wait to arrive till the last item? Like this:

*The United States **,** its allies, and partners are imposing harsh costs on Moscow.*

Is "The United States and its allies" considered as one item?

Comment: Are these partners, just partners of the U.S. or are they partners of the U.S. and their allies?

Comment: *[**The United States**] and [**US allies and partners**] are imposing harsh costs on Moscow.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat, good observation - "its" distributes to allies and partners. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence makes the United States the main player. You might consider “its allies and partners” one item, as “its” refers both to both allies and partners. In your version “partners” needs another “its,” which changes the connotation just a bit.

Comment: Thank you: There is no list.

Comment: Xanne, Thanks. I'm curious to understand the connotation that missing with "the US, its allies, and its partners" compared to "the US and its allies and partners". I'm wondering if the latter covers countries that could be both?

Comment: @YosefBaskin, thanks. I think Xanne is saying "the US and its X and Y" is a list with only two items. A longer list (series) like "the US, X, Y, and Z" will have conjugation before the last item. Both are lists. They differ in item count.